# I want to disable a button when asp RequiredFieldValidator shows error

Tags: asp.net

I want to disable the form submit button when asp:RequiredFieldValidator shows error
please advise

Comment: Why cant you go for a custom validator.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Page_ClientValidate("SomeValidationGroup") == false)
   document.getElementById("button1").disabled = true;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i need to do it in client side. is there any event to fire when somevalidation fail?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this javascripot function `onchange` of the control which triggers validation:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat=server OnChange="txtValidate();" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator  id="validator1" runat="server"
   ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ...>

<script>
function txtValidate() {
   // trigger validation from clientside
   var val = <%= validator1.ClientID %>;
   if (val.isvalid == false) {
     document.getElementById('btnSubmit').disabled = true;
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tim:i have many controls with validation for each one. i can't handle onchange event for each of them

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```
    function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
        if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) {
            //disable button here
            return false;
        }
        //enable button here
        return true;
    }
```

For more information about this function visit and understanding the ASP.NET Validation Library visit [this post](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/UnderstandingASPNETValidationLibrary.aspx).

Alternatively, as @Nag suggested, a custom validator may also be able to accomplish this as you are able to define the client side JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You should use validationgroup + requirevalidation then the button should not be clickable

Comment: This is not the case as the button is clickable, it just won't post back because the validation will prevent that.

Comment: Yes, not clickable and not usable are somehow similar concepts to me.

Comment: @kleinkie: you are right thats exactly what happens.when validation fails and the client fills the form again i want to enable the button